# In what situation we're allowed to put verb before a subject?

Tags: syntax

I read this in a novel:

> 'It's - it's true?' faltered Professor McGonagall.

Why <strike>it's</strike> is it not "Professor McGonagall faltered" (Subject + verb)

Comment: In fact, your question is an example of one: it should be "In what situations **are we** allowed..."

Comment: In fact, the question title here is a context where we ***must*** invert subject+verb (because it's a ***question***, it should be ***are we***, not ***we're***; the actual title as posted is a syntactically invalid form typically produced by non-native Anglophones). This aspect of usage isn't particularly related to the business of using either ***said John*** or ***John said***, BEFORE OR AFTER the actual words spoken by John.

Comment: (One could make the same point about ***the actual words spoken by Professor McGonagall*** in the example. Strictly speaking, it should be ***'Is it - is it** true?' faltered Professor McGonagall.* But the lack of inversion for a question isn't uncommon in such contexts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your example text and your suggestion would be correct - either are acceptable.

In texts with dialogue, it is extremely common to use other verbs in place of 'said', as a way of indicating who spoke the dialogue.

For example:

- "Sorry", said John.
- "Sorry", whispered John.
- "Sorry", blubbered John.

It is a way of avoiding constant repetition of 'said' which can get very boring in a long text; but a good choice of alternative can quickly convey the manner in which the dialogue was said without having to make another statement about their actions. In your example, the Professor evidently faltered as he spoke. And just as with 'said', you have a choice of placement:

- "Sorry", John said.
- "Sorry", said John